# Make it appear as if only one activity has launched when implementing a EULA

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, eula

I'm trying to implement a one time EULA and password creation screen in my app.

I strife to do this as clean and seamless as possible. My current implmentation involves a SharedPreference that needs to be set, when it's not, it should display the EULA and password creation screen.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isFirstLaunch(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences reader = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String apiKey = reader.getString(APIKEY, "");

    return apiKey == "";
}
```

The API key is set when the user completes accepting the EULA and has created a password. However I see the previous activity still being launched/animated. So I have been trying remove the animation on the first activity, but no luck as of yet.

**In the activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    if (InitialLoading.isFirstLaunch(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndUserAgreementActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        //getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        finish();

        return;
    }

    if (InitialLoading.isPasswordLoginEnabled(this)) {



    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Do you guys know how I can make it look as if only one activity has been launched in all scenario's:

- (DO NOT DISPLAY)lauched activity -> EULA -> Password Creation -> launched/other activity
- (DO NOT DISPLAY)lauched activity -> Authentication screen -> launched/other activity
- lauched activity

I currently still see a flicker of the previous activity when I try to launch the EULA. I have checked Whatsapp and that app does show a flicker when launching the non-EULA activity, so I wonder if this is possible.

I already have a settings screen that disables the password screen that would launch if the authentication option remains enabled, so no worries there.

Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Make your EULA `Activity` the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` and have it check to see if the user has accepted the EULA and created a password in the `onCreate` method. if they have then start the main `Activity` and immediately `finish()` the EULA `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may have a look at is the concept of [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).
The idea is to split the UI of your activity into reusable Fragments that can be interchanged at runtime.

So in your `onCreate` method, you can check whether a EULA screen is needed and then inflate the corresponding EULA Fragment, or in the other case display the password ui Fragment. 
This should reduce the flickering by avoiding to start a new activity in favour of reusing the active one.

Comment: As dumb as it may sound, but I completely forgot about fragments. Thx I found the solution to my problem.